# MySql Query to return different alias for same column grouped by date for line chart

Tags: mysql, sql, charts, pivot

I'm trying to do some report line chart graphs and find it easiest if I return one data row from my query for each column (date) of data that will appear in a line chart. The challenge is that I want more than one line.

Here is what I can do with a simplified example of data:

```
    |  DATE      | SALES | LOCATION |
    | 2012-01-07 | 500   | 1        |
    | 2012-01-07 | 600   | 2        |
    | 2012-01-14 | 700   | 1        |
    | 2012-01-14 | 400   | 2        |
    | 2012-01-21 | 450   | 1        |
    | 2012-01-21 | 550   | 2        |
```

SELECT date,  sum(sales) as SalesTotal1 FROM `TABLE` WHERE location = '1' group by date

Which returns:

```
    |     DATE   | SalesTotal1 |
    | 2012-01-07 |     500     |
    | 2012-01-14 |     700     |
    | 2012-01-21 |     450     |
```

That's fine if I just have one line in my graph but what I really want in more than one alias of the same column still grouped by date that would return this:

```
    |     DATE   | SalesTotal1 | SalesTotal2 |
    | 2012-01-07 |     500     |     600     |
    | 2012-01-14 |     700     |     400     |
    | 2012-01-21 |     450     |     550     |
```

Is this possible? Sub query? I've tried many things, thanks ~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
SELECT `date`, 
       SUM(IF(location=1,sales,0)) As SalesTotal1,
       SUM(IF(location=2,sales,0)) As SalesTotal2
FROM my_table
GROUP BY `date`
```

You'd have to add in as many columns as there are locations though, and if you have many locations it would be annoying. Perhaps you could consider doing the re-arranging on the code side (if you have many, many locations)?

Comment: Much thanks to all, this answer was a quick easy solution for my need.

Comment: This looks close to something I need, using the IFs. I have been using a UNION, but it only groups results under the aliases of the first SELECT. I need something like:
`IF( WHERE description LIKE '1.1 %') AS desc1,
IF( WHERE description LIKE '1.2 %') AS desc2`
is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is called a PIVOT table query which is not generally supported by MYSQL.  However, if you know exactly the locations you can do it with a chain of sub-queries.  If you don't know the exact locations you have to write a stored procedure that looks up the locations and builds a query string and then executes.  Here's how to do two locations:

```
SELECT
    date,
    SalesTotal1,
    SalesTotal2
FROM (
    SELECT
        date,
        sum(sales) as SalesTotal1
    FROM TABLE
    WHERE location = '1'
    group by date
) S1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        date,
        sum(sales) as SalesTotal2
    FROM TABLE
    WHERE location = '2'
    group by date
) S2 ON S1.date=S2.date
```